# Wifi is not working in 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers

My wired connection is working in ubuntu 16.04 but my wireless connection is not 
I have pasted the details here http://paste.ubuntu.com/23652092/
Please help me

Comment: The output does not show any wireless adapter installed. At least I cannot find it.

Comment: According to the output posted by you, there is no wireless adapter in your system. This might be due to faulty hardware. Can you use wireless adapter in any other OS?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `blacklist bcm43xx` is the issue in kernel. If you still have the live DVD, insert it, then in the live DVD:

1. go to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag bcmwl-kernel-source to your desktop
2. pool > main > d >dkms and drag dkms to you desktop
3. `cd ~/Desktop
   sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
   sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb`
4. Reboot